# Object type does not implement IComparable

Tags: c#, object, compare, icomparable

I've got a LinkedList class, where every node has a data and their data are generic type T

```
public class LinkedList<T> where T : IComparable
{
}
```

In its methods I compare data of nodes, but
as we know, object type doesn't implement IComparable,

```
LinkedList <int> listTest = new LinkedList<int>(); //it's OK
LinkedList <object> listTest2 = new LinkedList<object>(); //it doesn't work
```

but how can I compare all types that could be instead of T?

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding the use of IComparable. Can you tell me what are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: @CaveCoder well, I use CompareTo method to compare generic types. CompareTo can compare ints, strings and so on, but it cannot compare objects, because objects doesn't implement IComparable. I want to make it possible to compare objects too.

Comment: But why do you want to use object? you need to create a list with a more derived class as generic argument

Comment: @CaveCoder actually, I don't want to, but it's my homework in university and my teacher asks to make it possible to work with objects.

Comment: If your generic type is constrained to only accept types that implement `IComparable`, then, you can only use types that implement that interface. That's what generic constraints do. The `object` type does _not_ implement any interfaces.

Comment: This is almost literally asking for the ability to compare apples and oranges...`object` can be anything, any comparison would not make sense. That said similar functionality (like `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` allow the caller to pass an `IComparer<T>`, you could create the same construction for your `LinkedList<T>` and then create a custom `IComparer<object>`. Keep in mind though that, like `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` you might have to throw run-time exceptions when no comparing is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use the object type because it does not implement IComparable and break Generic Constraint.

You need to create a new object that implements the IComparable interface.

```
public class Foo : IComparable {
}

var list = new LinkedList<Foo>();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how is it possible to create a new object, if it's already an existing type? I don't need to put into a list my own classes. Just object type.

Comment: why do you need object type?